# Can I retrieve information about Instagram Stories (such as reach and number of comments) using the Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story, instagrapi

Can I retrieve information about Instagram Stories (such as reach and comment count) using the Instagram Graph API?
As far as I've researched, it seems possible to retrieve reach and comment count for feeds and reels, but I couldn't find any websites mentioning the ability to retrieve such information for stories.

Is it possible to retrieve metrics such as reach and comment count for stories, similar to feeds and reels?